# Passing a variable produces error code "ByRef argument type mismatch" for "..."

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create a personalized mass email and get the error code

> “ByRef argument type mismatch” for “mail_body_message”

in line `mail_body_message`.

[image]

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.Body = mail_body
    olMail.Send

End Sub


Sub SendMassEmail()

    row_number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Dim mail_body As String
        Dim full_name As String
        Dim promo_code As String
        mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("J2")
        full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number) & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
        promo_code = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "promo_code_replace", promo_code)
        MsgBox mail_body_message
        Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "This is a test e-mail", mail_body_message)
   Loop Until row_number = 6

   MsgBox "complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: First step: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables.

Comment: try `Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number).value`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @BigBen, add `Option Explicit` at the top of the code. That will force you to declare the variables.

**Imp Note**: Just declaring them will not solve your issue. You need to declare them as the `Right Type`.

In `Sub SendEmail()`, the parameter `mail_body` is declared as `String`. So in simple language, you need to declare a variable as `String` before you pass it through. These two example will make it clear for you.

**SAMPLE A**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim mail_body_message

    mail_body_message = "Blah"

    SendEmail mail_body_message
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(mail_body As String)
    MsgBox mail_body
End Sub
```

[image]

**SAMPLE B**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim mail_body_message As String '<~~ Declaring it as the RIGHT TYPE

    mail_body_message = "Blah"

    SendEmail mail_body_message
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(mail_body As String)
    MsgBox mail_body
End Sub
```

[image]

You may also want to read up on this error [ByRef argument type mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch)